# Rails API vs NSDate - Precision issues when comparing dates

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, nsdate

My iOS app consumes from a rails API that outputs JSON formatted dates with 3-digit microsecond precision, as per example below. This is parsed and saved for the corresponding entity, and NSDate retains the 3 digit precision as expected:

```
{ "updated_at": "2015-02-24T22:37:57.683Z" }
```

When I send this date back to the API for querying records, my `updated_at` field in the database seems to have (at least) 6 digit precision:

```
>> my_model.update_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N')
>> 2015-02-24 22:37:57.683977000
```

This means every time I query for

```
>> ios_date = json_hash["updated_at"]
>> Model.where("updated_at > ?", ios_date)
```

I get one record that already exists in my app's database.

I know I can add half a second to my `ios_date` to workaround this issue but this is obviously a hack.

Can anyone recommend what is the most appropriate course of action in this case?

TIA

Comment: You're not far off but check out the NTP article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks Anthony I had a look at that link but still fail to see how that helps with my question?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks like a good solution. I'll do some tests with it and let you know what happens. I'm using postgresql if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think the best approach would be to store in the database and output as JSON *exactly* the same thing, to avoid any needs of conversion or rounding issues like that one. As I assume you'd like to preserve the 3-digit microsecond precision dates, I'd just configure your database to store dates with that precision as well.

You can use a migration to modify the precision of the :created_at and :updated_at fields like this:

```
class MicrosecondsMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :your_table, :created_at, :datetime, precision: 3
    change_column :your_table, :updated_at, :datetime, precision: 3
  end

  def down
    change_column :your_table, :created_at, :datetime
    change_column :your_table, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

I believe that this will work with the major databases. [Check this commit at Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/96ce1f2553f895bfd25e7ca677fb7ed746d04fdd) where support was added for Postgresql. If you are on MySQL, please note that only [MySQL 5.6.4 and above](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-4.html) supports DATETIME's with more precision than a second. That is not your problem, you already said your database stores 6 digits precision datetimes, but I think it's worth noting here.

There are other approaches I can think of, though none looks better than the one described above, they may be worth noting as well:

- Change your query using some SQL to strip the extra digits from your date. I don't recommend going down that road: you'll need to take that into account in every query you need to do. Buggy, defeats AR purpose and looks ugly.
- Manually adding some milliseconds to your `ios_date`, which feels uglier.
- Of course, you can always change your JSON API to support the full 6 digits precision that your database handles. As I said before, I assumed that was not your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the option of changing the precision limits for created_at and updated_at was a valid option, the cleanest / most "Railsy" solution I've found was to get `to_json`'s output to match the database precision.

This can be achieved with one line of code:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision = 6
```

In practical terms this didn't really solve the problem as the underlying storage type for timestamps is a float so some time comparisons were still failing.

In the end reducing the precision was the way to go for me as per answer from @dgilperez on this page.

Comment: Good to see you solved your problem! I understand you went for the JSON precision extension to 6 digits (good thing to know it can be done!), but it still did not work for you since time comparisons kept failing. Can you show a practical example of such failures? And just out of curiosity: why are you then marking that approach as the accepted answer?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've accepted your answer as correct. My issue was specific to `NSDate` on iOS only returning 3 digits precision so the comparisons were still failing.